# How to use existing project's cpp file in VS

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm working with VS2010. And Now I have a existing project. I add it to the solution which include my new project. I have set the include dependency. But I want to use the existing project's .cpp file instead of liberary. What can I do?

Comment: Just add the cpp file to your new project using drag & drop (plus putting it into the correct folder first)? Don't see the specific problem here, so you might want to elaborate a bit more. :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Does it mean the only way is to put the files I need in my new project. I have thought I could just tell the IDE where to find these file.

Comment: @progmDong Adding the file to the project is the thing that tells the IDE where the file is.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to move the file. Just adding it can be enough based on your use case (but it's not necessarily the best strategy to do). If you're still using the old project, it might be better to actually create a library project.